# Require('jquery-ui') in node-webkit produces navigator not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, node-webkit

I have installed `jquery` and `jquery-ui` via npm for my node-webkit project. 
I also have a `index.html` which is loaded by node-webkit at startup and which loads a `core.js`.

This `core.js` requires both `jquery` and `jquery-ui`. When I start the app I get a `navigator is not defined` error. I tried googling it but found no solution. Has anyone an idea what causes this?

Comment: Show us your code. Also, **jQuery needs to be the first script you import. Make sure it is, before your** `core.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is unrelated to jquery-ui. I can reproduce it with

```
// index.html
<script>
require('./test.js');
</script>

// In test.js
console.log(navigator);
```

This is a limitation of node's `require`, which [only copies over the values of `global`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/a5778cdf01425ae39cea80b62f9ec6740aec724a/lib/module.js#L415), but navigator is not actually in `global`. Just specifying `navigator` works in the browser's context since the implicit globals are *not* provided by the `global`, but the `window` object (try `window.x = 2; global.x = 3; console.log(x);`).

To fix this problem, you can simply initialize global with the required variables from `window`, or fix the code in question (i.e. jQuery UI) to prepend references to navigator with `window.`. This should do for jQuery UI:

```
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
require('jquery-ui');
```