# node.js - ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

I'm getting **ReferenceError: navigator is not defined** running the following code on node.js:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I assume that the problem is that ***Navigator.geolocation*** is a Web API and doesn't work on node. Is there a way to mock the browser and use it on node.js?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require(processing-js) throws Reference Error: Navigator not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910623/requireprocessing-js-throws-reference-error-navigator-not-found)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the location of the computer Node.js is running on? Write unit tests for code that is intended to run in a browser (but with tests that run via Node.js)? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to mock the browser and use it on node.js?

One library that is useful for mocking Web APIs is `browser-env`.

```js
import browserEnv from 'browser-env';
```

Then:

```js
browserEnv(['navigator']);
```

This pollutes the global namespace, though, so be circumspect in its use.

Answer (score 4):

So I created this because analytics does not support node, so it requires conditional importing

```
import isNode from 'detect-node'
export async function analyticsLogEvents(event, params) {
  if (!isNode) {
    const firebase = await import('firebase/app')
    await import('firebase/analytics')
    firebase.default.analytics().logEvent(event, params)
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. The isNode condition solves a big problem for me re: Next.js initializing route logic in Node (and the same logic being run later by the browser). I was on this stuck for several hours. Really, thanks again.

Comment: @JohnCamden no problem, it took me like 2 days to find what was happening in my project because of the complexity between node and libraries and the react rendering, I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 4):

global.navigator worked for me:

```
global.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a server side technology, which means it can't access the user's geolocation directly.

What you should be asking is how to get geolocation using javascript on the client side, and then simply send that information to your server via Ajax.

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp .

There are of course libraries that will ease the use of this.

Answer (score -1):

Use BrowserEnv. You should get more infomation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-env. Hope can help you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31452171)